# Is it possible to expose the anaglyphic L/R shots in the compositor?

Tags: compositing-nodes, stereoscopy, output

I'm asking because I'm trying to come up with a way to render a sequence of frames, including both standard and anaglyphic left and right, in a single run. This could be done with the compositor fairly easily, if I could get a layer input for left and right; but it doesn't seem to be obvious.

It seems like the only real solution is to have manually adjusted additional cameras for the left and right eye, and manually cut channels from them in the final overlay; but if there's something easier then I imagine someone here will know about it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To render and save individual files for left and right view and the combined anaglyphic view in a single run, you can use the *File Output* node in the *Compositor*.

My example image isn't so exciting, but anyway: in the *Compositor* I placed two *File Output* nodes. In the screenshot of the *Node Properties* you can see that one is set to *Views Format* > *Individual*, the other to *Stereo 3D*. If you now press <kbd>F12</kbd> to render, three files will be saved:

- The left and right view images called **cubes_individual0001_L.png** / **cubes_individual0001_R.png**
- and the anaglyphic image called **stereocubes0001.png**

The names "cubes_individual" and "stereocubes" are set under *File Subpath* in the *Node Properties*, the frame number will always be attached and cannot be changed, and of course the suffixes _L and _R to indicate the side are added automatically.

[image: stereo files]

You do not have to add two *File Output* nodes necessarily, if you render an animation where the image sequence is saved automatically, you can simply set the regular output settings to create the anaglyphic image and a single *File Output* node for the individual views or vice versa.

Just one thing, what you are struggling with is getting the left and right view separated in the *Compositor*. I must admit I don't find a way to do this either.

For just saving the left and right view you won't need that, but let's say you want to composite the left and right view differently. In the above setup I just added a *Glare* node to the image. But maybe I want for example a glare on the left side and change the hue of the right side.

To achieve this you can add the *Switch View* node (under *Add* > *Converter*). This node has two inputs *left* and *right* and a single *Image* output. So you can plug the *Render Layer* output into different nodes, use the individual results in the individual inputs and get an *Image* where the left and right side are separate compositions.

[image: switch view]

By the way, it is very annoying but I didn't find a way to show the left and right side in the *Backdrop* of the *Compositor* to directly see the separate compositions added to the views. What you can do is either switch between left and right in the *Image Editor* where the *Render Result* is shown:

[image: image editor]

Or you can use a *Split Viewer* node instead of the regular *Viewer* node in the *Compositor*. This will still show only one view of the stereo image, but you can plug different inputs into the two *Image* inputs so you can work on the left and right composition simultaneously. The *X* and *Y* buttons let you decide if you want to split the view vertically or horizontally, the *Factor* going from 0 to 100 is the percentage how much of the second *Image* input is visible. But note: the second image will be overlayed from left to right resp. from bottom to top (which in my screenshot makes the left side of the backdrop show the right view composition).

[image: split viewer]

Comment: Thanks, this is a great answer. I'm sorry I didn't find time to check for it sooner.

Comment: @MichaelMacha No problem, you're welcome. If you'll ever find out how to display the left and right view separately in the _Compositor_ let me know.

Comment: If I ever do, I'll update my question. My best guess at the moment is rigging my own binocular camera, but that's kind of brute-force for my tastes.

Comment: Just to be clear, you already tried setting the file output properties to "Individual" instead of "Stereo 3D"? That usually does trigger a binary output (one for each eye), but I've never played with it in the compositor.

Comment: Of course, that's what I usually do to get the individual files. But still, in Blender - after rendering - I can only switch between left and right view in the _Image Editor_, not the _Compositor_. However, since I never ever felt the need to composite the left and right view different from each other (for example, why would I want a stereo image where I add glow to one side but not the other... or change colors etc. only for one side?) it is not really that much of a big deal.

Comment: My concern is that my ultimate rendering platform may vary—I could have one group using anaglyphic, another viewing on Oculus or Google Cardboard, and some boring bum looking at in 900p. If I can render all of them at once—standard, left, right, and anaglyphic—it may substantially save me some time. I'll let you know when I've got it all figured out, I'm a little buried in a different project right now unfortunately...

Comment: Oh, you need standard, too... the problem with this is, you can render the scene with _Stereoscopy_ enabled or not. You can choose to deselect the left or right view so that only one gets rendered, but this would result in having only one view for the anaglyphic render as well, and only the _L or _R files (deepnding on which view you choose). So if you want everything I suggest rendering anaglyphic, left and right as described above and then duplicate outside of Blender either the _L or _R files without a suffix to use as standard.